# OpenIdDict encryption key per application

Tags: openiddict

I was wondering if it is possible to set an encryption key per application in OpenIdDict?
Every application would use it's own encrpytion key.

All I see is an option for setting an encrpytion key on the global level with

```
.AddCore(options => { options.AddEncryptionKey(..) }
```

I was looking in the OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor when creating an application but I could not find such an option.